# Compilcated text parsing on Linux

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have some file with following structute:

```
main test1
slave something1 and something2
  something1
  something2

slave something3 and something4
  something3
  something4

main test2
slave something5 and something6
  something5
  something6
```

how can I modify this file to:

```
  test1something1 and test1something2
  test1something1
  test1something2

  test1something3 and test1something4
  test1something3
  test1something4

  test2something5 and test2something6
  test2something5
  test2something6
```

`somethingM` and `somethingN` not qeual, they can be totally different for example
`something1` can be `apple`
`something2` can be `banana`

With `sed`/`awl`/`perl`

Comment: IMO, this task would be much easier with a language that supports variables (awk, perl, sh). Is there a reason you need sed?

Comment: I can use `sh` or `awk` Could you write example

Comment: Can you explain the rule that says `test1` is prepended to both `something1` and `something2`, but not to the word `and` in between? Is it "the first and the last word", "all words except the word `and`"?, ...

Comment: Sed could do this:  `sed -e '/^main /{s/^main //;h;d};/^slave/{G;s/^slave \(.*\) and \(.*\)\n\(.*\)/  \3\1 and \3\2/g;};/^  .\+/{G;s/^  \(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/  \2\1/}' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$1=="main" {prefix=$2; next} {gsub(/something/, prefix "&"); print}' <<END
main test1
  something1 and something2
  something1
  something2

main test2
  something3 and something4
  something3
  something4
END
```

```
  test1something1 and test1something2
  test1something1
  test1something2

  test2something3 and test2something4
  test2something3
  test2something4
```

Comment: Needs `test1` prepended to both `something1` and `something2`...

Comment: oops, missed that requirement. Edited

Comment: Actually the "requirement" is not at all clear... your current solution matches the output asked for but I don't think it's what OP wants. I'm holding off my vote until that is clearer (but it's a good start. And the suggestion to use `awk` is definitely the right one.) I suspect there will be more edits in your future!

Comment: Sorry for not full question. I fixed it. Please see update.

Comment: @Pepelac, your edit didn't help. You need to provide a more "real" example input text, and clearly state the rules to generate the desired output